# Yii error when try to create model through gii

Tags: php, yii2

I have a error when trying to create model through Gii.Im going to this adress http://hostname/index.php?r=gii and have this error

```
Database Exception – yii\db\Exception

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'yii2basic'
↵
Caused by: PDOException

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'yii2basic'

in W:\XAMPP\htdocs\basic\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Connection.php at line 602
```

Answer (score 1):

You  should assign  the proper value in you db.php config file

look in your  basic\config   directory for the file  \db.php  and then assigne the proper valur for the database, the username and the password

```
return [
   'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yii2basic',
                                           ^^^ assign your correct dbname
    'username' => 'root',  // assign you  correct username  
     'password' => '',     // assign your password 
    'charset' => 'utf8',
 ];
```